# How to put dot navigation in UIkit sliders

Tags: javascript, css, html, getuikit

How do you add dot navigation for uikit's slider component. I tried,

```
<div data-uk-slider>
  <div class="uk-slider-container">
    <ul class="uk-slider uk-dotnav uk-grid-width-medium-1-4">
      <li><a href=""><img src="image1.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="image2.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="image3.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="image4.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><img src="image5.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

But only the dots are showing?

Comment: There's no suggestions about dotnav in slider inside documentation, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

As [cssBlaster21895](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5173560/cssblaster21895) mentioned the UIkit documentation only provides direct dotnav integration into the slideset component, however the dotnav documentation hints that it can be integrated into all other UIkit components.

Basically you can add the usual dotnav HTML inside the slider:

```
<ul class="uk-slider-nav uk-dotnav">
    ...
</ul>
```

Then include the dotnav component JS & CSS.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/css/components/dotnav.min.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.2/js/components/dotnav.min.js

See my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bassmanpaul/myeuyx17) for a more detailed explanation of how this can be achieved with a working example.